# DOJO CSVWriter not getting display data

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am using a dojo EnhancedGrid with the exporter plugin.
The grid has many displayed fields and several editable ones.
Among the editables I have one DateTextBox and two FilteringSelects that have formatters attached, to display the "displayValue" instead of the actual value in the store.
For example here is my Supplier field: (I copied the formatter from [kgf] in the dojo forums)

```
{field: 'SupplierId', name: 'Supplier', editable: editable, widgetClass: FilteringSelect, width: 6,
    widgetProps: { 
         store: comboSupplierStore, 
         searchAttr: 'name', 
         labelAttr: 'name'
   }, 
   formatter: function(data, rowIndex) { /*[kgf]*/
        /*alert("data "+data)*/
        var genId = 'supplier_' + rowIndex;
        var store = this.widgetProps.store;
        var attr = "name";

        setTimeout(function() {
             store.fetchItemByIdentity({
                  identity: data,
                  onItem: dojo.partial(displayValue, genId, store, attr)
             });
        }, 50);
        /*for now return a span with a predetermined id for us to populate.*/
        return '<span id="' + genId + '"></span>';
   }
}, /*Next field, and so on...*/
```

When I export a csv string, I get the SupplierId instead of the SupplierName in the string.
I have a button in which I defined the onClick event to export to csv string:

```
grid.exportGrid('csv', function(str){
    /*I do something with the string */
}
```

Could someone help me see why the exporter "ignores" the formatter?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you returning the id in the formatter,

```
'<span id="' + genId + '"></span>';
```

which is an id with 'supplier_' prefix:

> var genId = 'supplier_' + rowIndex;

Comment: No, 'supplier_' + rowIndex is not the actual id of the supplier. rowIndex is the index of the row of data from the store used to populate the EnhancedGrid. Each row can contain a different supplier, and there can be (and are) multiple rows that contain the same SupplierId. This Grid represents Purchase Demands.